# Batch File to change DPI Scaling Factor

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to write a batch file that will change a users DPI settings when they first login. I've placed the file in the startup folder and it will prompt the user to logout before any changes are made to the registry. I don't want the users to be prompted if the changes are already made. This is what I have so far:

```
        @echo off
REG QUERY "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics" /v AppliedDPI  
IF %var% == 0x78 GOTO Leave
CD\
CLS
ECHO.
:LOOP
ECHO Would you like to logoff to change Scaling of windows?
ECHO.
ECHO   Y = Logoff
ECHO   N = CANCEL and return to Windows
ECHO.
SET Choice=
SET /P Choice=TYPE YOUR CHOICE AND PRESS ENTER: 
IF NOT '%Choice%'=='' SET Choice=%Choice:~0,1%
ECHO.
IF '%Choice%'=='y' GOTO LogoffNow
IF '%Choice%'=='n' GOTO Leave
ECHO "%Choice%" is not valid. Please try again.
ECHO.
GOTO Loop
:LogoffNow
ECHO.
REG ADD "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v DpiScalingVer /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00001018 /f
REG ADD "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontDPI" /v LogPixels /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000144 /f
REG ADD "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics" /v AppliedDPI /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000144 /f
REG ADD "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Win8DpiScaling /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000001 /f
REG ADD "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v LogPixels /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000078 /f
shutdown /l
:Leave
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change line 2 to read:

```bat
REG QUERY "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics" /V AppliedDPI|FIND "0x78">NUL&&GOTO Leave
```

Also if you were to use the CHOICE command, *`Choice /?` for usage*, you could replace your entire `:LOOP` section with:

```bat
:LOOP
ECHO.
CHOICE /M "Would you like to logoff to change Scaling of windows"
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO Leave
:LogoffNow
```

Comment: Thanks for helping Compo! Worked like a charm! I new to scripting and I see where I went wrong.